# How can I line up my numbers in the middle of a table <td> cell?

Tags: html, css

I have the following:

```
<td id="refKey_1">1.0</td>
```

The numbers appear on the left hand side. Is there a way that I can make them appear in the middle of the cell ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can do this

```
<td align="center" valign="middle" id="refKey_1">1.0</td>
```

-------------or

in css

```
td#refkey_1{
text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

With CSS, you could do

```
text-align:center
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<td id="refKey_1" style="text-align:center;">1.0</td>
```

Or using css

```
tr td#refKey_1{ text-align:center }
```

Answer (score 0):

`<td align="center">` would be the easiest and quickest.